# Response.BinaryWrite not working with IE6

Tags: asp.net, response.write

I'm using the following C# code in some ASP.NET to send a file to the browser:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + myFileName);
Response.BinaryWrite(myContent);
Response.End();
Response.Close();
```

It works well with `WebDev.WebServer` and IIS7, under IE7-8, FF3-4 and Chrome. But not under IE6. I can't see why it can be a browser related issue...

Comment: For this browser you probably have to add the `content-length` header as well.

Comment: What exactly isn't "working well" in IE6? Don't you get the file, is the name wrong, ..

Comment: it's Content-disposition. IE6 was, afaik, case sensitive, in some cases.

Comment: Same thing with Content-disposition :( What is wrong with IE6: I don't get the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, here is the answer: it was due to Ajax in the page, and the Ajax request wasn't disabled as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `content-length` header:

```
Response.AddHeader("content-length", myContent.Length.ToString());
```

Edit: another one that might be required is `content-type`:

```
Response.AddHeader("content-type", "type here");
```

Comment: Please describe what exactly happens in IE6.

Comment: Nothing... the page refreshes, IE6 doesn't show the file download dialog.

Comment: @Francois that's weird.. can't you test on different server allowing you to store files, with the `SendFile` or `TransmitFile` methods?

Answer (score 0):

instead of BinaryWrite, use [TransmitFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12s31dhy%28VS.80%29.aspx). see example [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/dmiyamasu/archive/2008/02/25/save-server-memory-with-response-transmitfile.aspx)

Comment: Can't do that (can't store file on the server).